# Do the SDA read secular books during the Sabbath day?

Tags: sabbath, law, seventh-day-adventists, doctrine

I was reading the Mishnah and I came across this article which says it is unlawful to read secular material during the Sabbath but one is allowed to read only the written law and the oral law(after it was written down)

Shabbat 23/2

> Introduction This mishnah has to do with reckoning certain types of accounts on Shabbat.
> A man may count his guests and his appetizers/desserts by word, but not from writing. A host may want to count his guests or his food before or while the meal is being served. He may do so but he may not count them from a written list. The Tosefta explains that this is forbidden because it is acting on Shabbat the way one acts during the week. In the Talmud they explain that if he reads from a written list and sees that someone is not there or hears that they are not coming, he may erase their name from the list, a prohibited activity on Shabbat. ***Alternatively, he may grow accustomed to reading bills, lists and other types of business documents that a person should not read on Shabbat***

Seeing that the SDA are keen observers of the Sabbath day/Shabbat,Is this law also binding to the present day Adventist?

Comment: No we don't read secular books / material in the Sabbath day, except for maybe some text about nature where we get to know about the wonders of creation. All activities of the day trend to glorify God.